# Factorization Domain in which every domain generated by two elements is a principal domain, is a PID

Tags: abstract-algebra, principal-ideal-domains

Let $R$ be a factorization domain in which every ideal generated by two elements is a principal domain. Show that $R$ is a PID.

---

So let $I \subset R$ be an Ideal, then I have to show that there exists $a \in R$ so that $I=(a)$. I need some hint. What do I know about an arbitray Ideal $I$, so that I can use the premise and show the existence of such an $a$?

Comment: Most "domain" should be "ideal"...

Comment: Does being a factorization domain imply being noetherian?

Comment: By the hypothesis, every finitely generated ideal is principal. If there is an ideal which is not principal, then it can not be  generated by finitely many elements, then you can find an strictly ascending principal ideals chain, then by ufd condition, then......